# twitter4j_3.0.3 not working with https

Tags: https, twitter4j

Unfortunately our servers has Java 1.5 which is not compatible with twitter4j latest version. Recent change in Twitter to use https made our applications not to work. I tried to override the URLs by setting Configuration. But it is not fixing the issue. Please help.

```
ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder=new ConfigurationBuilder();
confBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
confBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
confBuilder.setHttpRetryCount(3);
confBuilder.setHttpRetryIntervalSeconds(30);
confBuilder.setRestBaseURL("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/");
confBuilder.setStreamBaseURL("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/");
confBuilder.setSiteStreamBaseURL("https://sitestream.twitter.com/1.1/");
confBuilder.setUserStreamBaseURL("https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/");
confBuilder.setOAuthRequestTokenURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
confBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
confBuilder.setOAuthAuthorizationURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
confBuilder.setOAuthAuthenticationURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate");
Configuration conf=confBuilder.build();
Twitter twitter=new TwitterFactory(conf).getInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 1.5 is no longer maintained. It reached its EOL four years ago.
You should upgrade your JVM version.

Answer (score 1):

please try this code by SSL insted of HTTP's

```
ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder= new ConfigurationBuilder();
confBuilder.setUseSSL(true);

confBuilder.setOAuthRequestTokenURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
confBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
confBuilder.setOAuthAuthorizationURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
confBuilder.setOAuthAuthenticationURL("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate");

TwitterFactory Tfactory = new TwitterFactory(builder.build());
Twitter twitter = Tfactory.getInstance();
```